# How to customize String in specific range? - Swift

Tags: swift, string, nsattributedstring, nsmutablestring

I'm a beginner in Swift and I want to make a custom Label on some letters the font to be bigger, and on some others to be smaller.

Like on image:

[Click here to open the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tetc1.png)

So, the currency symbol and decimal points should be in a smaller font than other numbers.

The code I tried to implement is:

```
// Used this function to get the index of decimal point (.) from the string.
func getDecimalIndex(text: String) -> Int {
    let myText = text.firstIndex(of: ".")
    return myText?.utf16Offset(in: text) ?? 0
}

func setupLabel(text: String) {
    guard !text.isEmpty else { return }
    
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    let decimalStart = getDecimalIndex(text: attributedString.string)
    attributedString.addAttribute(.font,
                                  value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22),
                                  range: NSRange(location: decimalStart, length: attributedString.length))
    
    myLabel.attributedText = attributedString
}

setupLabel(text: "$1100.33")
setupLabel(text: "1100.33€")
```

Whenever I load the app, it crashes on this line:

```
    attributedString.addAttribute(.font,
                                  value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22),
                                  range: NSRange(location: decimalStart, length: attributedString.length))
```

And the error in console is:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'NSMutableRLEArray objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:: Out of bounds'**

What might be wrong?

Thank you in advance for your contribution.

Comment: "What might be wrong?" I think it might be exactly what the error message said: the range is out of bounds. Unless the `location` is `0`, the length `attributedString.length` is out of bounds. And the `location` is evidently _not_ `0`.

Comment: Yes I know that's clear, but for instance, if I make `location: 1` it works, but if `decimalStart` is 1, it crashes.

Comment: Correct. So don't do that. What's the question? If `decimalStart` is `1` then the length would need to be `attributedString.length - 1`. You cannot go beyond the maximum length.

Comment: That's the reason I used the function `getDecimalIndex(text: String)` and it never gets over the length. If it cannot find `.` it will return 0. 

So it never get's above `length`

Comment: I didn't follow that, sorry. The problem is that it _did_ find `.` and you are giving a number of characters following that `.` that is more characters than there are. Hence the crash. Why not try actually doing what I suggested? Change `NSRange(location: decimalStart, length: attributedString.length))` to `NSRange(location: decimalStart, length: attributedString.length - decimalStart))` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks @matt, it worked. I completely forgot that the `length` is the actual number of characters after `location`, the problem was that I was looking `length` as the ending index. For that reason it was crashing.

Comment: I'd recomment tthough to use maybe a `NumberFormatter` to construct your final `NSAttributedString`, retrieve the decimals with `currencyDecimalSeparator` & the currency symbol with `currencySymbol` maybe. To test, but if you have mulltiple localizaion possible, might be worth a look...

Comment: The question it's should be more clear and clean.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting `NSRange` for `attributedString` you can use several `string` with several `attributedString-attributes`.

```
func setupLabel(textSmall: String, textLarge : String) {
    let attributeSmall =  [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)]
    let attributeLarge =  [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)]
    
    let attr1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textSmall, attributes: attributeSmall)
    let attr2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textLarge, attributes: attributeLarge)
    
    attr2.append(attr1)
    
    myLabel.attributedText = attr2
}
```

use this function by splitting your string with `.`

```
let yourValue = "$1100.33"
let smallTxt = yourValue.components(separatedBy: ".")[1]
let largeTxt = "\(yourValue.components(separatedBy: ".")[0])."
setupLabel(textSmall: smallTxt, textLarge: largeTxt)
```